# Java Arrays: how to ensure the semantic correctness of indexes used?

Tags: java, arrays, correctness

I have the following situation:

```
final int I  = 10;
final int MU = 100;
final int P  = 100;

int[][] a = new int[I][MU];
int[][] b = new int[I][P];

for(int i = 0; i < I; i++) {
  for(int mu = 0; mu < MU; mu++) {
    for(int p = 0; p < P; p++) {
      a[i][mu] = ... // something
      b[i][p]  = ... // something
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am using several arrays which have the same dimension, but which run over different indices. In this code, the following mistake may cause an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since `mu` has a larger range than `i`:

```
a[mu][i] = ...
```

In principle, I can catch this error. However, the following error is much harder to catch:

```
b[i][mu] = ...
```

Here there will be no runtime exception, since `mu` has the same range as `p`. This errors does cause semantic problems in the code, though.

Finally, my question: what is the best way to program these arrays in such a way that array `a` can only be accessed with the correct indices (`i` and `mu` in this case)?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Do not catch `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. 2) Best way is to carefully write and test your code.

Comment: Firstly it does not makes sense to have 2 separate final variables (constants) with same value. Also to answer the question you need to explain what you need triple nesting for. For me it makes more sense to have 2 double nested loops (one for each 2D array) then triple nesting.

Comment: prashant, you are right about the nesting, but that is a problem with my example, maybe I should have reduced it to the smallest possible example and show no loops at all!

This is because the situation I'm thinking of, at is essence is when you have to indices that can should be used to access different arrays but can be mistakenly used in the wrong array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you should really encapsulate your data better. Any time you have two collections which are always the same size, consider changing to have *one* collection of some type which composes them.

We can't really tell what your type is meant to represent (hint: use more meaningful names) but if you had a class:

```
class Foo {
    private final int[] a = new int[MU];
    private final int[] b = new int[P];

    ...
}
```

Then you could have:

```
Foo[] foos = new Foo[I];
```

At that point it's very clear how the arrays are structured - you're very unlikely to do the wrong thing, because you'd have a loop such as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foos.length; i++) {
    Foo foo = foo[i];
    // Use foo
}
```

I'd also encourage you to use the enhanced for loop:

```
for (Foo foo : foos) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I agree with your solution, although would it affect performance? I have been in a situation where the Java Virtual Machine spent most of the running time creating objects (in this case, we would be creating a `Foo` object for every `i`).

Comment: Another question: say I use the new `for` syntax (`for(Foo foo : foos)`) and at some point inside the `for` I need the index `i` of `foo`. Is there an easy way to do this? (I'd hate to do `int i = 0;for(Foo foo : foos){ /*use i*/ i++; }`

Comment: @Gonzalo: No, if you need the index you should use a regular for loop.

Comment: @Gonzalo: I don't believe the JVM would be creating a new instance of Foo; `Foo foo` would simply be a reference (think pointer) to the existing `foo[i]` object. So, some very minute amount of memory is used on the stack, but this is ephemeral and wouldn't affect GC and that sort of thing.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Yes, you'd end up with a container object instead of just the arrays. But you should almost *certainly* not pay attention to that minute detail - that's micro-optimization, which should not be done until it's been proven to be relevant.

Comment: @PeterMularien: No, Gonzalo is correct in that in order to have the `MU  * I` and `P * I` values, we need `I` objects of type `Foo`. However, the difference in performance will almost certainly be negligible.

Comment: @Jon, you are correct :) I was looking too narrowly at the pseudocode you provided and not the original question. Thanks!